# CakePHP 3, display entire record row if a field is empty, otherwise do not display it

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have just started using CakePHP this week (required for my internship), and I am not really that good with PHP to begin with.
Anyhow, I require help with the following:

How can you make a record to only be displayed if it has an empty field?

[Sample reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXnGc.png)

Based on the above image, I only want the row with an empty Title/date to be displayed, while hiding the other.

And on a different page I want the same records to be displayed but this time around, only show the ones with completely filled fields, while hiding the ones with empty fields.

EDIT:

View:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $this->Number->format($user->id) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->username) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->name) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->phone) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->email) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->role) ?></td>
            <td><?= $this->Number->format($user->status) ?></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $user->id]) ?>
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $user->id]) ?>
                <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $user->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id)]) ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Model:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('users');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
}

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is required');

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required');

    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('name');

    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('phone');

    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->allowEmpty('email');

    $validator
        ->add('role', 'inList', [
            'rule' => ['inList', ['admin', 'editor', 'sales_user', 'field_user']],
            'message' => 'Please select a role']);

    $validator
        ->add('status', 'inList', [
            'rule' => ['inList', ['1', '2', '3']],
            'message' => 'Please select a status']);

    return $validator;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);

    $this->set(compact('users'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
}
```

This is the first time I am posting a question, so please let me know if I need to include any further details or such.
Thank you.

Comment: In the model layer, query the database to get only the null value rows for a particular field. If you are using mysql as a database, check the mtsql query strings.

Comment: Oh, I see :D
I was requested to use sqlite, would it be possible to show me an example of an sqlite query used within cakephp 3?

Regardless, thank you very much!
How do I up vote your comment? :D

Comment: Please add your model and controller codes

Comment: Done, you can use any of the fields as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code selects the users where the name field is null.

```
public function index() {
  $users = $this->users->find('all', array("conditions" => array('name' => '')));
  $this->set("users", $users);
}
```